# Angularjs SEO improvements

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, web-crawler, web-search

**What are the major points at a glance to optimize an Angularjs-Website (with ui-router)?**

---

**1.**

Google is now able to render Websites with dynamic content, without the deprecated usage of their [Ajax crawling scheme](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2015/10/deprecating-our-ajax-crawling-scheme.html).

Our menu uses the "ui-sref" of ui-router like

```
<a ui-sref="about">About</a>
```

but google does not crawl any pages available from the menu.

We also usese the

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

which provides pretty and clean links (without hashtags)

Is it **necessary** to use [middlewares like prerender.io](https://prerender.io) which prerender Angularjs-Pages?

If the answer is **yes** isn't it than a disadvantage to use AngularJs for Websites?

---

**2.**

Without the use of the meta-tag 'description'

```
<meta name="description" content="some content">
```

page content gets rendered like

```
{{item.title}} (not the "ng-bind"-way)
```

how is it even possible to "serve" google the rendered page?

---

**3.**

An also interesting fact is the title-tag

```
<title>Lorem - Ipsum</title>
```

Sometimes google search results provide the title reverted like "Ipsum - Lorem" and sometimes it provides it correct "Lorem - Ipsum"

---

In fact there are many Blogs out there about this topic but many of them are outdated or way too unspecific.